# Is there a way to control the order of attributes when marshalling using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make @XmlAttribute in a special order by using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378936/how-can-i-make-xmlattribute-in-a-special-order-by-using-jaxb)

For readability, I need my marshalled xml to look like this:

```
<tag-name name="name" attr1="value1" attr2="value2"/>
```

Now, when I marshall it, it comes out like this:

```
<tag-name attr2="value2" attr1="value1" name="name"/>
```

Is there anything I can do about this? I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217734/reordering-xml-tags) that you can use `@XmlType(propOrder={"c","b", "a"})` or `@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)`, but I don't think those work with attributes.

My marshalling code is as follows:

```
public String writeClass(final Foo objectToBeMarshalled) throws JAXBException{
        // marshal
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(objectToBeMarshalled, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: @Perception It is a duplicate, I guess. Too bad there's no real answer...

Comment: Yea, its a shame. Why do you need the attributes sorted, apart from aesthetics?